# Facing Problems in Getting the values of textboxes in C# Web Application with details below:

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, textbox

I am facing issue in getting the values from `Post Method` from one view to another.
I have tried everything but still I cannot get the values.

Here is My Code:

`EmpController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;

namespace My_Work.Controllers
{
    public class EmpController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Emp
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Emp()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Emp(string name,string design)
        {
            ViewBag.Name1 =name;
            ViewBag.Design1 = design;
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult EmpDtl()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

`Emp` View:

```
   @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Employee Details</title>
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EmpDtl","Emp", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <h2>Employee Details</h2>
            <hr />
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Employee Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("Name")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Designation:</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("Design")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        }
    </body>
    </html>
```

`EmpDtl` View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Details</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Employee Details</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Employee Name: </span>@ViewBag.Name1
    <br />
    <span>Designation: </span>@ViewBag.Design1
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the code where I cannot get the values of textboxes on Post Method and I have tried everything but cannot find the issue. Any help will be appreciated to solve this issue.**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Details</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Employee Details</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Employee Name: </span>@ViewBag.Name1
    <br />
    <span>Designation: </span>@ViewBag.Design1
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use `TextBoxFor` instead of `TextBox`.

Comment: "and I have tried everything" - **no you haven't "tried everything"**. If you had tried everything you would have found the solution in using a ViewModel class to use with `HtmlHelper` and that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use the `ViewBag`. It's untyped and therefore unsafe. It should only be used for prototyping, imo.
- You need a ViewModel class (separate classes for each view or logical page) which represents both the content of the rendered page *and* the data that you want to bind from an incoming `POST` form request.

  - **DO NOT** use Entity Framework types as bound ViewModels: while it may seem convenient (and even some of Microsoft's older tutorials demonstrate this anti-technique) it introduces major security issues because it allows users to arbitrary specify values for any value (such as `UserId` and `Password`). Also *it just doesn't work* in practice because the contents of a web-page do not map 1:1 with a single database row or domain-entity: consider an "Edit user" page: it will have two password inputs ("New Password" and "Confirm password") those properties won't exist on your User entity class.

    - Also ASP.NET MVC uses different data-annotations to Entity Framework and they can conflict (e.g. `MaxLength` vs `StringLength`).
  - I note that an awkward limitation of ASP.NET MVC's design means you cannot have have multiple `<form>` elements on the same page if you use `HtmlHelper` to generate form inputs. There are ways around this but I won't go into detail as that's off-topic for this conversation.
  - Another annoying limitation is that if you use controller action method parameter binding (instead of using `UpdateModel` explicitly) you cannot have immutable viewmodel-types: they must have a default (parameterless) constructor, even if that puts the viewmodel object into an invalid state.

Anyway, this is what your View-Model would look like:

```
class EmployeeDetailsViewModel
{
    [Display( Name = "Employee Name" )]
    [Required]
    public string Name   { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

Change your `POST` action's signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Emp( EmployeeDetailsViewModel model ) // IIRC the parameter must be named "model" in ASP.NET MVC, I might be wrong. It's been a while.
{
    
}
```

And change your `.cshtml`:

- Tip: Use `nameof()` to ensure you have the correct Action Name.
- Unfortunately you cannot use `nameof()` for the Controller Name because the `Controller` class name suffix won't be bound correctly. (Yet another minor annoyance in ASP.NET MVC)

```
@model EmployeeDetailsViewModel

...

        @using (Html.BeginForm( action: nameof(EmpController.EmpDtl), controller: "Emp", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <h2>Employee Details</h2>
            <hr />
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Employee Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Name )
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Designation:</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Designation )
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        }
```